# Session gets lost before time set up

Tags: session, jsf-2, primefaces

I am working with primefaces 3.4 and JSF 2.0.4, I´ve set up the session to be over in 30 minutes in web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

And i have an iddleMonitor set up to show up in 25 minutes, however, suddenly the session gets lost, and iddlemonitor does not show up, and the application does not work,

Anybody has face this problem? any solution?

Comment: How do you use the idle monitor? Are you aware that a simple move of the mouse resets the idlemonitor, but **not** the session timeout

Comment: And what is 'suddenly'? Please make it smart

Comment: @Kukeltje suddenly is "5 minutes" aprox, and I´m aware of the movement of the mouse, after 5 minutes sometimes the session gets lost, but i can't figure out why...